# CASE statement conversion in DAX

Tags: dax

case
when ([Assessment Status]="Overdue") and (DateDiff("day",[Due Date],DateTimeNow())<30) then "Overdue by 0-30 days"

when ([Assessment Status]="Overdue") and (DateDiff("day",[Due Date],DateTimeNow())<60) then "Overdue by 30-60 days"

when ([Assessment Status]="Overdue") and (DateDiff("day",[Due Date],DateTimeNow())<90) then "Overdue by 60-90 days"

when ([Assessment Status]="Overdue") and (DateDiff("day",[Due Date],DateTimeNow())<120) then "Overdue by 90-120 days"

when ([Assessment Status]="Overdue") and (DateDiff("day",[Due Date],DateTimeNow())<150) then "Overdue by 120-150 days"

when ([Assessment Status]="Overdue") and (DateDiff("day",[Due Date],DateTimeNow())<180) then " Overdue by 150-199 days"

when ([Assessment Status]="Overdue") and (DateDiff("day",[Due Date],DateTimeNow())<>200) then "Overdue by 200 days"

else "In Progress" END

**How can i convert it into DAX? I tried to google it but I wasn't able to find anything useful. Can someone help me with that please. Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
case = SWITCH(TRUE (), [Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 30, "Overdue by 0-30 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 30, "Overdue by 0-30 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 30, "Overdue by 0-30 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 60, "Overdue by 30-60 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 90, "Overdue by 60-90 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 120, "Overdue by 90-120 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 150, "Overdue by 120-150 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) <> 180, "Overdue by 150-199 days",[Assessment Status]="Overdue" && DATEDIFF([Due Date],DateTimeNow(),DAY) < 200, "Overdue by 200 days","In Progress")
```

Based on the documentation of dax: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax

And this example:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Help-with-SWITCH-TRUE-with-multiple-items-to-evaluate/td-p/439241

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but there are records which are overdue by 200days  but now since we put <>180 I guess they are falling under overdue by 150-199 days. Is there any way we can get both overdue by 150-18 and overdue by200 days